# Ruby instance variable in a Puppet template (erb)

Tags: ruby, erb, puppet

I do not understand the behaviour of this Ruby code I have written inside a Puppet template (erb). It must be related to some property of instance variables that I ignore and have not been able to find out.

At the Puppet side a variable $local_users can be declared (and initialized) or not in the file site.pp. In the template code shown below, the if sentence checks if it has been previously initialized.

```
<% if @local_users -%>
  <%= fail('local_users has to be an array') unless local_users.class == Array -%>
<% else -%>
  <% local_users = [ "root" ] -%>
  <%# some code to add more users to the array -%>
<% end -%>
<% local_users.uniq.each do |user| -%>
  <%= user %>
<% end -%>
```

If $local_users is not declared in the site.pp file (else branch), this code works flawlessly. If it is declared (if branch), then it fails when trying to apply the Puppet manifest:

```
Failed to parse template sendmail/local-users.erb: undefined method `uniq' for nil:NilClass at /usr/share/puppet/modules/sendmail/manifests/config.pp:39
```

(line 39 is where the template is invoked: `content => template('sendmail/sendmail.mc.erb'),`)

The problem is that in the loop the local_users variable is not recognized as an Array. I solved the problem just declaring a local variable at the if branch:

```
<% if @local_users -%>
  <%= fail('local_users has to be an array') unless local_users.class == Array -%>
  <% local_users = @local_users -%>
<% else -%>
```

But inside the if branch **it is an Array**, since `local.users.class == Array` returns true (at this point I can use the method local_users.uniq too without problems). Furthermore, I have tried with `if local_users` (without @) and inside the if branch local_users is still an Array, but in the loop keeps failing.

Here are my questions:

1. How can this behaviour be explained? Why is the local_users variable an Array inside the if branch and not at the loop?
2. Is my workaround correct or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since in Ruby `nil` is an object with its own class (`NilClass`) and since (try this with `irb`):

```
nil.respond_to? :class
# => true
```

the statement `local_users.class == Array` return `false`.

`local_user` is a variable local to the view, while `@local_user` is an instance variable of the controller behind that view.

There are two different things, that's why you have to assign `local_user` to `@local_user` in order to not have a `nil` when ou invoke `local_users.uniq`.

Btw, why are you working with `local_users` instead of simply use `@local_users` and moving all the logic on the controller?

Comment: Ops, you're right: this hint make sense only on a strong MVC architecture.
All the rest remains.

Comment: Thanks @andrea. As @mark has said, I do not think "controller" is the best term in this case. By definition, an instance variable belongs to the object itself where it is created (i.e. self). In this case self is the whole template. Anyway, let me remark the strange behaviour I was referring to:  if I put `test_class = local_users.uniq` inside the if branch, it works (i.e. local_users.class is Array)! It is as if the scope of the local variable was the if branch...

Comment: By the way, it works fine if I always use `@local_users` (inside the if and else branches, and in the loop). It seems to be the way to follow. But, again, why is `local_users` an Array inside the if branch but not in the loop?

Comment: Can you better explain me what you mean when you say:

'...but in the loop keeps failing'?

Comment: Yes, I mean that at the line `local_users.uniq.each do |user|` local_users is nil (as you pointed on your first answer) and so I get the error message. The intended behaviour would be that local_users was an Array, as it is inside the if branch.